# Error de conexion sqldevelop y oracle problema de puerto de escucha

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hace poco formatee el ordenador y al instalar de nuevo oracle g11 y oracle sql develop intento conectar pero no hay manera me dice. se que es un problema de puerto pero nos e cambiarlo

```
 ora 12528
```

he intentado tambien con ocracleg11 por comando pero me dice connec timeout ocurrent

y tengo el examen el lunes asi que tengo que practicar una mano porfa

Comment: ese error de usuario y password no creo que podamos ayudarte con eso :/

Comment: De paso, tomate el tiempo en mejorar tus preguntas, aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron o completar las mismas si las resolviste vos mismo. Tene en cuenta que el sistema hace auditorias automaticas y puede penalizarte si ve que tus aportes no son positivos.

Comment: @gbianchi me resetado la clave pero me da un error de litener de puerto de escuha

Comment: Estonces no debe estar abierto el puerto.

Comment: me meto en el router y abro el puerto el 8080? como como lo hago @gbianchi

Comment: ni idea ni de tu red ni de nada que tengas.. y tu pregunta no especifica mucho. Tu db esta recibiendo conexiones por que puerto? a ese puerto te tenes que conectar...

Comment: te cuento lo que se. Mi red internet de jazztel mi windows 8.1 el puerto creo que es el 8080 porque lo he visto por ay al instalar o algo de eso pero no lose seguro

Comment: Me parece que estas confundiendo tus problemas. Tu oracle esta en otra pc o en la misma de donde te queres conectar? si es asi, la red no tiene nada que ver. Despues, al instalar oracle, te dio un usuario y pass por defecto para entrar como administrador. Tambien una cadena de conexion por defecto.. todo eso lo guardaste? probaste conectarte con eso?

Comment: yo lo instale y meti una clave al instalra pero no me dio ningun usuario ni nada. Claro oracle esta en el mismo ordenador donde queiero usarlo

Answer (score 1):

hace tiempo  me ocurrió algo similar con una instalación de Oracle 11g y 12c.  Revisa los siguientes  puntos, en los cuales puede darte solución:

- Puede que el ID de usuario no sea válido para el sistema de destino:
  el ID de usuario existe como la columna de nombre de usuario en la
  vista `dba_users`.
- Comprueba el parámetro de entorno `$ORACLE_SID`. Si tu $ ORACLE_SID
  está configurado con el ID de sistema incorrecto, entonces puedes
  obtener un error **ORA-01017** porque se está conectando a la base de
  datos incorrecta.
- Si utilizas la autenticación de usuario del sistema operativo externo
  (ops $ o remote_os_authent), debes verificar que la ID de usuario sea
  válida. Puedes saber si está usando autenticación externa porque se
  conecta sin proporcionar una combinación de usuario/contraseña, y
  solo proporciona una barra diagonal hacia la cadena de conexión (por
  ejemplo, `connect / as sysdba;`).
- **Comprueba  tnsnames.ora para asegurarte de que el nombre del
  servicio TNS apunta al servidor y al nombre de instancia correctos.**
  Si especificas un nombre de servicio `tnsnames.ora` incorrecto, es
  posible que la ID de usuario y la contraseña no existan en esa base
  de datos.

Comment: y todo eso donde lo miro?

Comment: Hola que tal, tipicamente en :  %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin

Comment: no encuentro niguna carpeta que se llame oracle_home

Comment: %ORACLE_HOME% hace referencia a la ruta donde instalaste tu producto de Oracle database.

Comment: no encuentro la carpeta network dentro de la clarpela de oracle donde esta istalado. encuentro una carpeta admin  tiene una carpe XE y dentro addump dbump y pfile

Comment: Vos instalate un oracle, o solo el cliente de oracle? me parece que solo instalo un cliente y por lo tanto no instalo ninguna base de datos. Vos tenes una base de datos oracle para instalar?

Comment: ya consegui connectar gracias nos e que pasaria